# renderInContext failing to render UIView that's greater than 512 pixels wide

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitextview

I have a view hierarchy that's over 600 pixels wide.  Inside that hierarchy I have a UITextView. Everything displays correctly on screen.

I then try to create an image from that view:

```
CGSize size = mainView.bounds.size;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, YES, 1.0);
[[mainView layer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
```

This works for the most part.

However, if the UITextView is wider than 512 pixels then the text isn't drawn. The view itself is visible (you can see the background), but there's no text.

This is on OS4 and OS5.

I assume that this is a bug, but I desperately need a workaround. Has anyone see this before?

Tim

Comment: Try setting the scale to 0.0 so its set automatically, also not sure why you need round the floats.

Comment: Hi. That makes no difference unfortunately. The rounding was irrelevant, I've removed that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've now fixed this. It's a curious iOS bug that's provoked when:

1. one of the text view's superviews isn't fully contained within its
   parent view.
2. the text view is over 512 pixels wide

Tim